# Website where people post their available hours on a shared calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, website, calendar

When planning a meeting in Outlook, I can see others' schedules and hours. I am looking for a similar functionality over the web through a web site. It doesn't have to use Outlook or expect people to use Outlook.

Is there a web site which offers a similar service where people post their available hours
 on a shared calendar, a calendar which is open to anyone, where the person enters their name and available hours and then this information shows up on the calendar?

The idea is have a bird eye view of the availability of everyone who entered their info.

Please don't post just any scheduling or calendering site. I need the specific requirements I asked for.

**EDIT**: The calendar has to reside on a webpage that doesn't require any kind of signups or joining anything. It should be totally open. Each person should be able to enter their name and hours. So Google Calendar is out if it doesn't meet this requirement. I don't like to force anyone to join it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [WhenIsGood](http://whenisgood.net/).  I've never used it, but it looks like it does exactly what you want, and they don't require a sign up/account.  Basically, you create an event/meeting, and then put all your invitees on a list, then they indicate through the site what time is good for them.

[Here](http://lifehacker.com/376434/when-is-good-finds-the-best-time-for-everyone) is a LifeHacker writeup on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for a similar service for a while, it is not perfect but I found that [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar) Seems to work.

You can set up multiple calendars, and then choose to share it with other contacts, either just busy/free time or more information.

Anyone can share with anyone, but they need to have a Google account (the only downside I have found). You can share events with anyone and other websites, but I have not found a way to share or put the calendar on another site (but this wasn't one of your requirements!)

Again, it isn't perfect, but it does work. You can select which calendars to show events from and then switch to day / week e.t.c. view and see the information.

I use it to share my project status with others.

Comment: I am looking for a solution more open to Google Calendar when anyone can enter their info without being a member.

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendar using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) lets you see the events and availability of everyone in that domain. I’m not sure if it’s exactly what you’re looking for, but it’s worth a try.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Meeting Wizard](http://www.meetingwizard.com/) isn't the same as Outlook, but it might meet your needs:

- Only the organizer (you) needs to login
- The organizer provides a list of possible dates and email address to send invitations to
- The people invited receieve an email with a webpage link showing a list of possible dates to indicate their availability
- The organizer gets a list of who's available which days, and who hasn't responded
- If desired, the invitees can see the list of who's available, and when
- A reminder email can be sent to the people who haven't responded
- New possible dates can be added, if required
- A final meeting notice can be sent, which can be imported into Outlook Calendar
- If desired, a list of email addresses can be kept in the application
- All this for free!

I tested this for a group I'm involved with, but they preferred to continue sending emails!